# Port forwarding to VPN

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

```
                                                 |
                                                 |WAN
                                             /-------\
  .------------------------------------------| switch|
 |                                           \-------/
 |  /--------------------\                        |
 |  |                    |     /-------------\    |
 `--|eth0            eth1|-----|192.168.1.1  |    |
    |1.2.3.4  192.168.1.2|     |      1.2.3.5|----'
    |                    |     \-------------/ VPN
    \--------------------/         router
           server
```

routings table:

```
10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1
1.2.3.4/29 dev eth0
default via 1.2.3.3 dev eth0
```

i want to do a port forwarding to access the 10.0.0.0/8 from internet.

iptabless rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:8000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:8000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.1 --dport 8000 -j MASQUERADE
```

but it doesn't work. please help. thanks.

Comment: Where is the 10.0.0.0/8 network?

Comment: It is encryption domain thats connected by vpn.

Comment: does anyone have some idea? which soft can do this?

Comment: Have you tried this for the last rule? `-j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.X`, where X is the IP of the router's VPN interface.